# load balancing in jboss fuse 6.2

Tags: fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have installed Jboss fuse 6.2 in 2 unix boxes and deployed camel-cxf-contract-first application bundle in both the servers.
first server is master box and second one is slave box.how do you configure this set up?if master node is down then requests
should automatically should forward to slave box.how do we set up it in latest jboss fuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Fabric for this. Once you have a Fabric and you have a CXF application deployed twice or more, you can use the http gateway components from Fuse to loadbalance any incoming requests over the available endpoints.

See here for documentation about the http gateway: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2/html/Fabric_Guide/Gateway.html

Comment: how to create a fabric?